# How to get the position of a character in Python?

Tags: python, string

How can I get the position of a character inside a string in Python?

Answer (score 935):

There are two string methods for this, `find()` and `index()`.  The difference between the two is what happens when the search string isn't found.  `find()` returns `-1`  and `index()` raises a `ValueError`.

#### Using [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

```
>>> myString = 'Position of a character'
>>> myString.find('s')
2
>>> myString.find('x')
-1
```

---

#### Using [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)

```
>>> myString = 'Position of a character'
>>> myString.index('s')
2
>>> myString.index('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

---

### From the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

> `string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])`
> Return the lowest index in *s* where the substring *sub* is found such that *sub* is wholly contained in `s[start:end]`. Return `-1` on failure. Defaults for *start* and *end* and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

And:

> `string.index(s, sub[, start[, end]])`
> Like `find()` but raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found.

Comment: What if there are duplicate characters in the string? Does this return a list?

Answer (score 184):

Just for a sake of completeness, if you need to find all positions of a character in a string, you can do the following:

```
s = 'shak#spea#e'
c = '#'
print([pos for pos, char in enumerate(s) if char == c])
```

which will print: `[4, 9]`

Comment: `foo = ( [pos for pos, char in enumerate(s) if char == c])` will put the coordinates **foo** in a list format. I find this really helpful

Comment: it's 0 indexed, 0123 as opposed 1234, so the actual position is 5, 10

Answer (score 60):

```
>>> s="mystring"
>>> s.index("r")
4
>>> s.find("r")
4
```

"Long winded" way

```
>>> for i,c in enumerate(s):
...   if "r"==c: print i
...
4
```

to get substring,

```
>>> s="mystring"
>>> s[4:10]
'ring'
```

Comment: Thanks
Tell me how can we get the substring of a string according to the positions given...

Comment: @arung: to get the substring use slicing: `str[from:to]` where `from` and `to` are indices

Comment: s.find() return -1 if substring is not found

Comment: s.search() raises a ValueError when the substring is not found. 
s.find() returns -1 if the substring isn't found.

Answer (score 21):

Just for completion, in the case I want to find the extension in a file name in order to check it, I need to find the last '.', in this case use rfind:

```
path = 'toto.titi.tata..xls'
path.find('.')
4
path.rfind('.')
15
```

in my case, I use the following, which works whatever the complete file name is:

```
filename_without_extension = complete_name[:complete_name.rfind('.')]
```

Comment: This is helpful for finding the extent of a string. For example, finding a dictionary could be: `left = q.find("{"); right = q.rfind("}")`.

Comment: If you're trying to find the extension of a filename, the better way to do it now would probably  be with Pathlib. `from pathlib import Path; p = Path("toto.titi.tata..xls")`.  Then `p.suffix == ".xls"` and `p.stem == "toto.titi.tata."`

Answer (score 17):

What happens when the string contains a duplicate character?
from my experience with `index()` I saw that for duplicate you get back the same index.

For example:

```
s = 'abccde'
for c in s:
    print('%s, %d' % (c, s.index(c)))
```

would return:

```
a, 0
b, 1
c, 2
c, 2
d, 4
```

In that case you can do something like that:

```
for i, character in enumerate(my_string):
   # i is the position of the character in the string
```

Comment: `enumerate` is better for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 14):

```
string.find(character)  
string.index(character)
```

Perhaps you'd like to have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to find out what the difference between the two is.

Comment: From that linked documentation: 
s.search() raises a ValueError when the substring is not found. 
s.find() returns -1 if the substring isn't found.

Answer (score 8):

A character might appear multiple times in a string. For example in a string `sentence`, position of `e` is `1, 4, 7` (because indexing usually starts from zero). but what I find is both of the functions `find()` and `index()` returns first position of a character. So, this can be solved doing this:

```
def charposition(string, char):
    pos = [] #list to store positions for each 'char' in 'string'
    for n in range(len(string)):
        if string[n] == char:
            pos.append(n)
    return pos

s = "sentence"
print(charposition(s, 'e')) 

#Output: [1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 6):

## **If you want to find the first match.**

Python has a in-built string method that does the work: [index()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_index.asp).

```
string.index(value, start, end)
```

Where:

- Value:    (Required) The value to search for.
- start:    (Optional) Where to start the search. Default is 0.
- end:      (Optional) Where to end the search. Default is to the end of the string.

```
def character_index():
    string = "Hello World! This is an example sentence with no meaning."
    match = "i"
    return string.index(match)
        
print(character_index())
> 15
```

## **If you want to find all the matches.**

Let's say you need all the indexes where the character `match` is and not just the first one.

The pythonic way would be to use `enumerate()`.

```
def character_indexes():
    string = "Hello World! This is an example sentence with no meaning."
    match = "i"

    indexes_of_match = []

    for index, character in enumerate(string):
        if character == match:
            indexes_of_match.append(index)
    return indexes_of_match

print(character_indexes())
# [15, 18, 42, 53]
```

Or even better with a list comprehension:

```
def character_indexes_comprehension():
    string = "Hello World! This is an example sentence with no meaning."
    match = "i"

    return [index for index, character in enumerate(string) if character == match]


print(character_indexes_comprehension())
# [15, 18, 42, 53]
```

Comment: This doesnt work when you look for a string not a character

Comment: The question was about an individual character, not a string. So I answered the question ;)

Answer (score 4):

[`more_itertools.locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.locate) is a third-party tool that finds all indicies of items that satisfy a condition.

Here we find *all* index locations of the letter `"i"`.

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


text = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
search = lambda x: x == "i"
```

**Code**

```
list(mit.locate(text, search))
# [8, 13, 15, 18, 23, 26, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most methods I found refer to finding the first substring in a string. To find all the substrings, you need to work around.

For example:

#### Define the string

vars = 'iloveyoutosimidaandilikeyou'

#### Define the substring

```
key = 'you'
```

#### Define a function that can find the location for all the substrings within the string

```
def find_all_loc(vars, key):

    pos = []
    start = 0
    end = len(vars)

    while True: 
        loc = vars.find(key, start, end)
        if  loc is -1:
            break
        else:
            pos.append(loc)
            start = loc + len(key)
            
    return pos

pos = find_all_loc(vars, key)

print(pos)
[5, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with numpy for quick access to all indexes:

```
string_array = np.array(list(my_string))
char_indexes = np.where(string_array == 'C')
```

Comment: Please don't use this method. There is no reason to bring numpy into a simple string indexing operation.

Comment: It depends, if you have millions of rows in a csv file you can perfectly use Numpy