# How would I Create a second attack input in a battleship adviser without using a bunch of if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

After changing my code to what R.Sharp has suggested everything works completely fine but I still can't find a tutorial or anything on how I could create the second attack

```
 Rank= input("What is your rank?")
Name= input("What is your name " + Rank + "?")
grid= input("What would you like the length of your grid to be " + Rank + " " + Name + "?")
Attack1=input("Where do you want to attack first " + Rank + " " + Name + "?\n" +"(Please print with capital letters)")
grid= int(grid)
#Removing the Number from the Letter
RemoveNum = Attack1[0].upper()

#Removing the letter from the coordinates
RemoveLetter = Attack1[1].upper()

RemoveLett=int(RemoveLetter)

row = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".split()
col = "A B C D E F G H I J".split()

x=col.index(RemoveNum)
y=row.index(RemoveLetter)

possibles=[] # blank list to store suggestions in

if x > 0 :
    possibles.append(col[x-1] + row[y]) # left
if x < grid-1:
    possibles.append(col[x+1] + row[y]) # right
if y > 0 :
    possibles.append(col[x] + row[y-1]) # up
if y < grid-1:
    possibles.append(col[x] + row[y+1]) # down

# Construct string of all possibles except the last
poss_list = ','.join(possibles[:len(possibles)-1])

if possibles > grid:
    pass

#Printing First Suggestions
print("You could try {0:s} and {1:s}".format(poss_list,possibles[-1]))
```

Comment: Because you're supplying a negative index. If x=0, x-1=-1 and a negative index supplied to a list counts backwards from the end. so col[-1] is the last entry in the col list or 'J' in your example. Try checking if x(and y) are >0 to pick left (and up) and < grid -1 to pick right (and down.) Then you don't need the try:...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay - this really isn't an answer, but I wanted to put in some code snippets and use more characters than a comment would allow.

I would recommend re-thinking your approach.

You say you want to be able to vary the grid size, but then your function `As()` is explicitly hard-wired to a row length of 5.

step one - try to decompose the problem into an engine, or engines, which work on generic assumptions you can have about the data, And a set of data.

For example, to allow for grids up to 10 by 10, define 2 lists of indices :

```
row = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".split()
col = "A B C D E F G H I J".split()
```

Now, google for a way to get the position in the col list, of the letter that was input or read this : [How to get the position of a character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294493/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-character-in-python)

I'm going to refer to this as `x`

Convert the row value you extracted to an int as before and subtract one as in python lists the first index is zero.

I'm going to refer to this value as `y`

So if I had input 'D7' x would be 3 and y would be 6.

```
x=3
y=6
```

Because the grid is regular you know that the 4 locations around the one you've been given as (x,y) are :

```
Left  = (col[x-1] + row[y])
Right = (col[x+1] + row[y])
Up    = (col[x] + row[y-1])
Down  = (col[x] + row[y+1])
```

So to get the 4 points round the one indicated all you need to do is :

```
print("you could try {0:s}, {1:s}, {2:s} and {3:s}".format(Left, Right, Up, Down))
```

which gives :

```
you could try C7, E7, D6 and D8
```

What you need to consider now is how to handle when your indices go outside your grid. i.e. what to do if x or y are zero, or 9 and how to restructure the output text accordingly.

build the calculation of Up, Down, Right and Left into a function, along with appropriate checking of the indices and then you're ready to handle more complicated advice based on the size of the vessel you're trying to hit and eventually storing known hit locations so you don't advise shooting somewhere that's been hit before.

I hope that helps.

## ==> Based on your edited question - does this help :

```
Rank= input("What is your rank?")
Name= input("What is your name " + Rank + "?")
grid= input("What would you like the length of your grid to be " + Rank + " " + Name + "?")
Attack1=input("Where do you want to attack first "
              + Rank + " " + Name + "?\n" +
             "(Please print with capital letters)")

#Removing the Number from the Letter
RemoveNum = Attack1[0].upper()

#Removing the letter from the coordinates
RemoveLetter = Attack1[1].upper()

row = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".split()
col = "A B C D E F G H I J".split()

x=col.index(RemoveNum)
y=row.index(RemoveLetter)

possibles=[] # blank list to store suggestions in

if x > 0 :
    possibles.append(col[x-1] + row[y]) # left
if x < grid-1:
    possibles.append(col[x+1] + row[y]) # right
if y > 0 :
    possibles.append(col[x] + row[y-1]) # up
if y < grid-1:
    possibles.append(col[x] + row[y+1]) # down

# Construct string of all possibles except the last
poss_list = ','.join(possibles[:len(possibles)-1])
#Printing First Suggestions
print("You could try {0:s} and {1:s}".format(poss_list,possibles[-1]))
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help :)