# Matching a User Input to a string?

Tags: python

i am trying to print some code which matches the User's Input to the previous String Input. Then display where the character is matched (Like the game Hangman).

The '-' indicates what the first string will look like, each '-' will be removed once a correct guess has been entered. Now i have tried to use a '==' method but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick, does anybody have any suggestion?

```
word_guessed = input("Enter a Word to be guessed: ")
type(len(word_guessed))
print(len(word_guessed)* '-')

guess_letter = input("Enter a letter to be guessed: ")
if guess_letter == word_guessed:
    print("Correct Guess, Guess again: ")
    print("The Letter is located:" == len(word_guessed))
else:
    guess_letter = word_guessed
    print("Incorrect Character, again.")
```

Comment: You need to compare the letter your user enters, to each letter in your word. What you have now compares your letter to the entire word.

Comment: That is what i am trying to do but i have tried to use the '==' method which doesn't work so i am unsure on how to compare characters to one another.

Answer (score 1):

I had some code lying around that I extracted the most relevant parts. Read it through and I think it answers your question:

```
alpha = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") # valid inputs
secretword = "animal" # the secret word
found = [] # list with letters that are found

while True:
    print(' '.join(i if i in found else '_' for i in secretword))

    # Only accept valid inputs
    while True:
        inp = input("Guess a letter [a-z]: ")
        if inp in alpha:
            break
        else:
            print("Not valid!")

    if inp in secretword:
        print("Nice")
        found.append(inp) # add letter to found list
        alpha.remove(inp) # remove letter from alpha (valid inputs)

    # If len of unique letters (set) in secretword equals len found
    # Break the game
    if len(set(secretword)) == len(found):
        print("You won")
        break
```

Comment: Champion! Thank you very much, i just extracted some of the code to other program's and work like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: @Morph glad to hear and good luck in the future. Also consider marking my answer as an answrer :)

Answer (score 0):

First part, to check if a letter or symbol is in a string:

```
if letter in string: 
    # do something
```

This will return true whenever "letter" in its exact form is present in the string. Different capitalisation, entered spaces or other differences will register as false, so you may want to clean up your user's input before checking it.

> a = 'Factory'
>
> False
>
> 'f' in a False
>
> 'F' in a
>
> True
>
> 'F ' in a
>
> False (Note the space after F)

Second, to find the indices of the letter(s) there are several ways:

```
mystring.index('letter')
# Returns the index of 'letter', but only the first one if there are more than one.
# Raises ValueError if not found.
```

Or we can use list comprehension to iterate through the string and return a list of all the indices where 'letter' is: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794963/8812091)

```
indices = [index for index, char in enumerate(mystring) 
           if char == 'letter']
# Go over the string letter by letter and add the letter position 
# if it matches our guessed letter.
```

Third, to update the string with found letters we iterate over the '----' string and put in the guessed letter at the correct positions. See below.

Putting it into your script:

```
word_guessed = input("Enter a Word to be guessed: ")
type(len(word_guessed))
print(len(word_guessed)* '-')



current_guess = str('-' * len(word_guessed))
# The current state of the guessed word fixed as a variable for updating
# and printing.

guess_letter = 'F'
# Fixed input letter for testing with the word "Factory".

if guess_letter in word_guessed: 
    letter_indices = [index for index, char in enumerate(word_guessed) if char == guess_letter]
    # Or if you want to show only one (the first) of the guessed letters:
    # letter_indices = word_guessed.index(guess_letter) 
    print("Correct Guess, Guess again: ")
    print("The Letter is located:", letter_indices)

# Now update the current guess to include the new letters.
current_guess = ''.join(guess_letter if index in letter_indices 
                        else char for index, char in enumerate(current_guess))
# We can't change strings, so we build a new one by iterating over the current guess.
# Put in the guess letter for the index positons where it should be, otherwise keep 
# the string as is. ''.join() is an efficient way of combining lots of strings.

print(current_guess)
```

> Enter a Word to be guessed: Factory
>
> "-------" (Added " to avoid SO autoformatting)
>
> Correct Guess, Guess again:
>
> The Letter is located: [0]
>
> F------