# How to copy a variable string located in a specific location from a text file in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to copy a string which is located at third place in a text file.
Though I can count the character and copy the string based on their character index, I am afraid for some of the files this strings might have more or less number of characters.
For example, in the below line I have third string as `239.943`; for some other file it could also be `1022.345` or `98.234`.

```
       1  51 239.943   .2081   .0137   .2016   .0017
```

Is there any way to identify and copy the third string i.e., `239.943` irrespective of its character length in python?

Comment: Can you post your file and the expected output please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no such thing to post. I am reading a text file, which has these numbers at second line. I am reading the line and want to copy second string. Likewise I will be copying second string iteratively for multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Read line by line, split by spaces and read `array[2]` from the obtained array.

```
with open(filepath) as fp:  
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        arr = re.split(r'\s+', line)  
        print arr[2]
        line = fp.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2294502/7244300.

```
>>> s = "I have a cat"
>>> s.find("have")
2
```

Comment: Surely not the problem.