# how to create code which finds a space within a string using the .find tool or a similar tool

Tags: python

How do you find a space within a string using the `.find` function or a similar function?

I'm trying to create a code that finds a space within a string, so that I can separate the string into two parts.

If this is too vague, or you don't understand, please comment.

Comment: You mean if string is " This is Stack Overflow", you need to count number of spaces i.e. 3 in this case ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please note that this is not a code implementation service, normally people do some effort their own and come here with specific questions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @toti08 All I was asking is how to find a space within a inputted string

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by "find a space"? Detect if one or more are present? Get the index of the space? Or simply split the string on the space? On all spaces? You have to be much more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the position of a character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294493/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-character-in-python)

Comment: See also: [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to find spaces in a string, according to your needs.

You can use the find method to find the most left occurence

```
your_string.find(' ')
```

alternatively, you can find the most right occurence

```
your_string.rfind(' ')
```

you can also find all occurences with a comprehension list

```
[index for index, ch in enumerate(your_string) if ch == ' ']
```

You can also split all strings by space with

```
your_string.split() #Split by space by default
```

Comment: You can also do it with the re library, but I am not sure that's what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you very much, Great detail.

Comment: Nice and complete answer.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I have completed the code thanks to you! You are a legend!

Answer (score 1):

Well, not understandable, but i think `split`:

```
s='a b'
print(s.split())
```

It converts to list with two strings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count spaces:

```
a =  "My Testing String"
a.count(' ')
```

Comment: I want to see other answers, I want to test out different ways before I do.