# ajax to an html site is getting 200 but the response is empty

Tags: javascript, ajax

An example:

this is the site I'm trying to get the HTML:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294493/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-character-in-python`

and the AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: "get", //send it through get method
        success: function(response) {
                var htmlElem = $($.parseHTML(response));
                console.log({response})
         },
         error: function(xhr) {
                //Do Something to handle error
         }
        })
```

the response is empty (`""`) all the time, can someone know why? and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Loading cross-domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX

this is not fixinig the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading cross-domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-endpoint-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Are there any errors whatsoever in your browser's console log?