# Replace regex in string with value from dict, while retrieving the index

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Given a dict and a string:

```
my_dict = {"X":"xxx", "Y":"yyy"}
my_str = "A[xxx]BC[yyy]"  # editted to comment below
```

I need to create two different strings:

```
> print(result_1)
'ABC'
> print(result_2)
1|X|3|Y
```

where *result_1* is *my_str* without the square brackets, and *result_2* is the index of that place in the string without brackets.

So far, I am able to find all square brackets with:

```
vals = re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', my_str)
for val in vals:
    print(val)
```

I know that I can find the index with *str.index()* or *str.find()* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294493/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-character-in-python), and I also know that I can use *re.sub()* to replace values, but I need to combine these methods with the lookup in the dict to obtain two different strings. Can anyone help me or put me on the right path?

Comment: Please verify if  `my_str = A[xxx]BC[yyy]` OR is is it `my_str = "A[xxx]BC[yyy]"` ?

Comment: @Wiktor: That will never happen, but I will let it throw an assert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a solution like

```
import re
my_dict = {"X":"xxx", "Y":"yyy"}
my_str = "A[xxx]BC[yyy]"

def get_key_by_value(dictionary, value):
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
    return value  # If no key has been found

rx = re.compile(r'\[([^][]*)]')
result_1 = rx.sub('', my_str)
result_2_arr = []
m = rx.search(my_str)
tmp = my_str
while m:
    result_2_arr.append("{}|{}".format(m.start(), get_key_by_value(my_dict, m.group(1))))
    tmp = "".join([tmp[:m.start()], tmp[m.end():]])
    m = rx.search(tmp)

print ( result_1 )
print ( "|".join(result_2_arr) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2GbIQi)

Output:

```
ABC
1|X|3|Y
```

The `result_1` is the result of removing `[...]` substrings from the input string.

The `result_2` is formed by:

- Looking for a `\[([^][]*)]` match in a string
- If there is a match, the start index of the match is taken, the dictionary key is searched for in the dictionary and in case it is there, the key is returned, else, the value is returned, and the match is removed from the string and the next regex search is done on the modified string. Then, the results are "joined" with `|`.

Comment: Thanks! But I still need to replace the "yyy" by it's key, "Y".

Comment: @Tim Fixed. `return value` should have been indented a bit differently.