# Want Python to tell where a randomly guessed letter is in a computer generated word

Tags: python, string

I'm making an elementary version of hangman and wish for the computer to tell the user where the correctly guessed letter is ("first", "second", etc.).  Here is what I have so far:

```
print("ok, I have just thought up a word.  It has ",word_count," letters in it.  Make sure you draw that many blank spaces.")
first_try=input("Ok, whats the first letter you want to guess?")
if first_try in mystery_word:
    print("Good guess it is the"    "letter(s) in the word")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647202/ordinal-numbers-replacement

Comment: what if the letter appears twice in the string?

Comment: I have thought about that as well...any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinal numbers replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647202/ordinal-numbers-replacement)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294493/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-character-in-python

Comment: Not really,  what I'm trying to do is if  the computer randomly picks the word "congress' from a list, and when asked for a letter, the user inputs 's'  I would like the computer to say "good choice, it is the 7th and 8th letters"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First use a list comprehension to get all the indexes in the `mystery_word` of the letter for `first_try` also add `1` since indexes start from `0`
- then use the `humanize` module all the indexes to the ordinal version (e.g. from `2` to `2nd`)
- Then just use `.join` to print the ordinals in a nice format along with the `Good guess it is ..."`

```
import humanize


mystery_word = "saample"
word_count = 5
print("ok, I have just thought up a word.  It has ",word_count," letters in it.  Make sure you draw that many blank spaces.")
first_try=input("Ok, whats the first letter you want to guess?")
if first_try in mystery_word:
    indexes = [(n+1) for n,x in enumerate(mystery_word) if x == first_try]

    indexes = [humanize.ordinal(index) for index in indexes]

    print("Good guess it is the",','.join(indexes),"letter(s) in the word")
```

**Output:**

```
ok, I have just thought up a word.  It has  5  letters in it.  Make sure you draw that many blank spaces.
Ok, whats the first letter you want to guess?a
Good guess it is the 2nd,3rd letter(s) in the word
```

Comment: Hey, is there any way to run the humanize function on an online compiler?  Keep getting an error when I run this code.

Comment: you would have to hard code the ```humanizer``` module or something similar