# Find what character appears next to a specified other in python

Tags: python

I’m coding in python. Is there a way to find what appears next to a specified other character. My string is A4B6C1D7. Using the code: `if “A” in string:`I would like to know if there is a way to then find out what appears next to it, so ideally: yes it appears in string and the number next to it is 4. It will always be a number next to the letter before another letter if this helps? Thanks!

Comment: See [How to get the position of a character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294493/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-character-in-python)

Comment: Will you only search one character? Can it be duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this i think:

```
myString = 'A4B6C1D7'
if 'A' in myString:
    ind = myString.index('A')
    nextLet = myString[ind+1:ind+2]
    print(nextLet)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find()` method of string to find where in the string the character lies. You can then pull the next character by adding one to that:

```
myString = 'A4B6C1D7'
print(myString[myString.find('A')+1])

>>>'4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no multiple instances of "A" for example:

```py
def get_value(char, full):
    if char in full:
        index = full.index(char)
        if index + 1 <= len(full) - 1:
            return full[index+1]

print(get_value("A", "A4B6C1D7"))
# 4
```